# How to center last items in multiple row list keeping height per row and same gap?

Tags: css

I have a list of items with an image and a brief description, and I want to show them in multiple rows, with the same height per item in the row, the same gap and centering the last row if it has less items.

[image]

In small resolutions there's no problem because I'll show just one item per row, but in bigger devices or desktop there will be a random number of items per row (responsive, according to the viewport).

It doesn't matter the layout option to be used, but it has to allow the following:

- Keep the same height for all the items (like default in grid or flexbox).
- Same spacing between items, but not at beginning or end of the row (like justify-: space-between)
- Last row centered if there are less items in it.

Ideally, the solution would be a mix of grid and inline-block but, sadly, CSS is far from perfect yet.

What could be the approach to achieve this with CSS, avoiding javascript?

I have analyzed different options but none of them resolves all of my needs.

**Grid:**
Great option to keep the same height between items, and a consistent gap, but last row can't be centered (at least whitout knowing the number of items).

**Flexbox:**
Same as grid but, justifying content with "space-between", the last row isn't centered, and the gap can't be fixed.

**Float:**
Always "aligned" left or right, can't keep the same height of items and the gap is also at the beginning and/or the end of the row.

**Inline-block:**
Allows centering of items, but can't keep the same height of items and the gap is also at the beginning and/or the end of the row. Besides, to cope with the extra space this *display* adds, I have to add a hack with font-size.

I wrote a [code to check all options](https://codepen.io/romualdinho/pen/gOOaNZM).

Relevant HTML:

```
<section class="secGrid">
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum<br>lorem line 2<br>Line 3 consectetur</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
/* Grid */
.secGrid ul { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); grid-gap: 20px; }

/* Flexbox */
.secFlex ul { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between; }
.secFlex li { flex: 0 1; min-width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px); margin-bottom: 20px; }

/* Float */
.secFloat li { float: left; width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px); margin-right: 20px; }

/* Inline-block */
.secInlineBlock ul { font-size: 0; text-align: center; }
.secInlineBlock li { display: inline-block; width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px); margin-right: 20px; font-size: 1rem; vertical-align: top; }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the code below has worked for me.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="flex-container">
   <li class="flex-item">1</li>
   <li class="flex-item">2</li>
   <li class="flex-item">3</li>
   <li class="flex-item">4</li>
   <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 10px 5px 0px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

I simply added `flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content:center;` to the container of the elements.
You might want to fiddle with the container and element sizes so they suit your needs. It seems that using `width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px)` doesn't allow the page to reflow, making it unresponsive. I would suggest using some other value to specify the width.

[image: result]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nazar-klymenko/pen/VwwapNK

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem using `justify-content:center` is that it keeps the margin of the first and last item of each row. For design reasons, first item of the row should start at 0% and last item end at 100% of the row.
For the same reason I can't use fixed width for the items. Anyway, the reflow of the page is not a problem, because I'll use percentages on items and with a couple of media queries I'll make them fit other screens.
If I can't find another answer i'll use `justify-content:center` and negative margins on wrapper but I don't like it. I feel it's kind of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox like below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  justify-content:center;
}

li {
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background:grey;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
li:before {
  content:"";
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum<br>lorem line 2<br>Line 3 consectetur</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is the same I mention in Nazar Klymenko answer. With margins on items I'll have to use `justify-content:center` and negative margins on wrapper, but I don't like it.